Dinamically Change the Image from a imageview that is in a recyclerview from the adapter
this stuff is beating me for hours. I want to change the image on a imageview that is inside a recyclerview from the adapter. The name of the image is coming from firebase (in the field Time from the model) and the image is at res\drawable. Can someone help me or point me to a tutorial? I'm a noobie with kotlin and android stuff.
Main activity
private fun getDataFromFirebase(){
binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("firebaseurl").reference
    .get()
    .addOnSuccessListener { dataSnapshot->
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
            for (snapshot in dataSnapshot.children){
                val quizModel = snapshot.getValue(QuizModel::class.java)
                if (quizModel != null) {
                    quizModelList.add(quizModel)
                }
            }
        }
        setupRecyclerView()
    }

my adapter
    package np.com.bimalkafle.quizonline

import android.content.Intent

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import np.com.bimalkafle.quizonline.databinding.QuizItemRecyclerRowBinding


class QuizListAdapter(private val quizModelList : List<QuizModel>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<QuizListAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
    class MyViewHolder(private val binding: QuizItemRecyclerRowBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(model : QuizModel){
            binding.apply {
                quizTitleText.text = model.title
                quizSubtitleText.text = model.subtitle
                quizTimeText.text = model.time + " min"
                quizImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.humanas)
                root.setOnClickListener {
                    val intent  = Intent(root.context,QuizActivity::class.java)
                    QuizActivity.questionModelList = model.questionList
                    QuizActivity.time = model.time
                    root.context.startActivity(intent)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val binding = QuizItemRecyclerRowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false)
        return MyViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return quizModelList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(quizModelList[position])
    }

My layout
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/blueblack"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:letterSpacing="0.1"
            android:text="Passei no Encceja"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="34sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Vamos estudar jogando juntos"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Todas as Disciplinas"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>


I kind of made it work with something really bad. I set my model field to var... from the activity class I recovered the id using resources getidentifier and then inside my adapter I set it using setImageResource... but that's really ugly. If someone can help I would apreciate

I found that your call your setup recyclerview below of the get the data. That's actually not a good work. My recommendations you can init your initial recyclerview in different call. For example in oncreate call the init variable.
In the other places, inside adapter you can create a new function called update the data. To call it after get the data from the firebase. And run recyclerview.notifyDataSetChanged() to update or refresh your recyclerview when there is new changes.
